# Shifting a column down in a time series in R

Tags: r, finance, yahoo-finance, quantitative-finance

I have the following code to download data from Yahoo Finance

```
#Libraries
library(quantmod);
library(forecast);
library(tseries);
library(timeSeries);
library(xts);

#Variable plug-ins
stockname = "NFLX"
startdate = "2010-01-01"
enddate = "2020-07-30"

#Pull data from Yahoo Finance
stockvar = getSymbols(c(stockname),src="yahoo", from=startdate, to=enddate,auto.assign = FALSE)
stockvar = na.omit(stockvar)

#Chart time series
chartSeries(stockvar, theme="white", name=c(stockname)[1])
```

And I want to pull the Close price series at column 4 of the Yahoo Finance dataset to a new dataset called price and move the column by one day down. For example from this:

```
            stockname.Close
2010-01-04  7.640000
2010-01-05  7.358572
2010-01-06  7.617143
```

to this

```
            stockname.Close
2010-01-05  7.640000
2010-01-06  7.358572
2010-01-07  7.617143
```

Comment: Please add the packages your code uses so that others can run your code.

Comment: I just added them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

x <- "            stockname.Close
2010-01-04  7.640000
2010-01-05  7.358572
2010-01-06  7.617143"

df <- read.table(text = x, header = TRUE) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "date") %>%
  mutate(date = as_date(date)) %>%
  mutate(date = date + days(1))
```

In the above R code, I read in your data first. Then create a date column, and lastly add a day to the date. The output is:

```
        date stockname.Close
1 2010-01-05        7.640000
2 2010-01-06        7.358572
3 2010-01-07        7.617143
```

which is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering I´ll try it now.

Comment: It works just how I wanted, my only question now is how do I change it so it does that for all the close price (column 4) values in the stockvar dataset downloaded from yahoo finance.

Comment: Assuming your dataframe is in order, e.g. the date column is in right date format, you should be able to use the last `mutate()` to do what I do in my example to your complete dataset.

Comment: My date column is in order, but I dont understand what you mean by the last `mutate()` , do you mean I need to change something in this line of your example **mutate(date = date + days(1))**, and if so what. And also will it work regardless of if I change the stockname, startdate, enddate variables? Thanks for all your attention.

Comment: You don't need to change much. Did you try: `df <- mutate(df, date = date + days(1))`? Assuming your dataframe is named `df`.

Comment: The code only changes the date by adding 1 day, it does not change anything else to the dataframe.

Comment: I added this to Pull Close price series at column 4 of the Yahoo Finance dataset
`price = stockvar[,4]
price <- mutate(price, date = date + days(1))` and I get this error **Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('xts', 'zoo')"**. Sorry for all the questions but I´m new at programming and r programming

Answer (score 0):

To select only the close column you can do :

```
stockvar[,  'NFLX.Close']

#           NFLX.Close
#2010-01-04   7.640000
#2010-01-05   7.358572
#2010-01-06   7.617143
#2010-01-07   7.485714
#2010-01-08   7.614286
#2010-01-11   7.604286
#....
```

To shift the column "down", you can use `lag`

```
stats::lag(stockvar[,  'NFLX.Close'])

#           NFLX.Close
#2010-01-04         NA
#2010-01-05   7.640000
#2010-01-06   7.358572
#2010-01-07   7.617143
#2010-01-08   7.485714
#2010-01-11   7.614286
#....
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: already checked on yours, but a window appeared and said that because I have less than 15 reputations my vote will be counted, but not shown publicly.

Comment: @DavidMuñoz Yes, you can't upvote but you can accept the answer by clicking on grey check mark on the left which is below vote button.

Answer (score 0):

I also found another way to do it myself using the following code:

```
#Pull Close price series at column 4 of the Yahoo Finance dataset
price = stockvar[,4]
```

and this to rename column to Lclose, shift price 1 row down and delete the first blank row:

```
names(price)[1] <- "Lclose"
price$Lclose[2:nrow(price)] <- price$Lclose[1:(nrow(price) - 1)]
price = price[-1,]
```